# Conditional formatting not seeing updates to dynamic range

Tags: excel, range, conditional-formatting

I have a dynamic range called Categories which I created using this formula:

`=$D$2:OFFSET(INDEX($A$1:$A$30,COUNTA$A$1:$A$30)),0,3)`

In Conditional Formatting I have the `=ISBLANK(D2)` as the condition and Categories as range to which to apply this condition.

Unfortunately, Excel converts my dynamic range to absolute values and only works once. If range boundaries change (I add a non-blank row to `A:A`, for example), the dynamic range updates correctly, but it's not carried through into Conditional Formatting as the values from the first time dynamic range was applied are recorded as absolute.

Is that a built-in limitation of CF or is there a workaround?

Comment: Perhaps it would be simpler to use this condition in CF - `=AND(D2="",A2<>"")` and use an "applies to" range that allows for expansion

Comment: OK, thanks - I'll post this as an answer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment......

Perhaps it would be simpler to use this condition in conditional formatting:

`=AND(D2="",A2<>"")`

....and use an `"applies to"` range that allows for expansion

Answer (score 1):

CF rules cannot retain a named range as their *Refers to:* parameter. Any named range will be translated to the range that it currently refers to when it is created. This is similar to attempting to use a named range as a chart parameter.

On a related note, I believe the following following adjustment to your dynamic named range formula will get rid of the volatile `OFFSET` function.

`=$D$2:INDEX($D$1:$D$30,COUNTA$A$1:$A$30))`